# Ionic app reflect old version UI after restart device or kill app from background

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic4

I have an issue with my Ionic app. The issue is very strange when I create a build from ionic dashboard and installed it in my device everything is working fine but if I am restarting the device or killing app from background and then I am opening the app is reflecting me old content. Like old UI screens.

I did following thing to resolve it.

1. Run `ionic platform remove android` then `ionic platform add android`
2. Run `cordova clean`

But these are not working for me.

**config.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.example" version="1.0.21" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>App Name </name>
    <description>App Name</description>
    <author email="hi@ionicframework" href="http://ionicframework.com/">Ionic Framework Team</author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <allow-navigation href="*" />
    <allow-intent href="*" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />
    <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false" />
    <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16" />
    <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
    <preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="0" />
    <preference name="loadUrlTimeoutValue" value="60000" />
    <preference name="android-windowSoftInputMode" value="adjustResize" />
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
    <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="true" />
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="300" />
    <preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="true" />
    <preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="true" />
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreen" value="true" />
    <preference name="UseSwiftLanguageVersion" value="4.2" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
        <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="28" />
        <icon density="ldpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" />

    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <edit-config file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge" target="NSCameraUsageDescription">
            <string>To scan barcodes</string>
        </edit-config>
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />

    </platform>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="1.1.4" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="2.2.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-sslcertificatechecker" spec="5.1.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-certificates" spec="^0.6.4" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-http" spec="1.2.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" spec="^6.0.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="^4.0.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic" spec="^2.0.4">
        <variable name="APP_ID" value="e363211c" />
        <variable name="CHANNEL_NAME" value="Production" />
        <variable name="UPDATE_METHOD" value="background" />
        <variable name="UPDATE_API" value="https://api.ionicjs.com" />
        <variable name="MAX_STORE" value="2" />
    </plugin>
    <plugin name="ionic-plugin-keyboard" spec="^2.2.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing" spec="^5.4.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1.3.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-datepicker" spec="0.9.3" />
    <allow-navigation href="http://192.168.2.26:8100" />
    <engine name="ios" spec="5.0.0" />
    <engine name="android" spec="6.3.0" />
    <engine name="browser" spec="5.0.4" />
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "App Name ",
  "version": "1.0.21",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "preinstall": "./cordovaOverride.sh",
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build --prod",
    "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
  },
  "config": {
    "ionic_source_map": "source_map"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/core": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/forms": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/http": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.1.3",
    "@ionic-native/app-preferences": "4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/barcode-scanner": "4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/date-picker": "4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/file": "4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/printer": "4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/social-sharing": "4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/sqlite": "4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "4.7.0",
    "@ionic/pro": "1.0.16",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.1.3",
    "@zxing/library": "0.5.0",
    "amazon-cognito-identity-js": "1.26.0",
    "angular2-signaturepad": "2.6.1",
    "aws-sdk": "2.156.0",
    "cordova-android": "6.3.0",
    "cordova-browser": "5.0.4",
    "cordova-ios": "5.0.0",
    "cordova-pdf-generator": "^2.0.8",
    "cordova-plugin-add-swift-support": "^1.7.2",
    "cordova-plugin-android-permissions": "^1.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-barcodescanner-browser-support": "7.1.22",
    "cordova-plugin-certificates": "^0.6.4",
    "cordova-plugin-datepicker": "^0.9.3",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^1.1.7",
    "cordova-plugin-file": "^6.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-http": "^1.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic": "^2.0.4",
    "cordova-plugin-printer": "^0.7.3",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^4.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-sslcertificatechecker": "^5.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.3",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
    "cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing": "^5.6.2",
    "es6-promise-plugin": "^4.2.2",
    "eslint-plugin-html": "2.0.1",
    "ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard": "^2.2.1",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.9.4",
    "phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner": "^7.1.2",
    "rxjs": "5.4.2",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "3.2.3",
    "@types/node": "8.5.1",
    "json-loader": "0.5.7",
    "typescript": "2.3.4",
    "webpack": "3.8.1"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-android-permissions": {},
      "cordova-plugin-sslcertificatechecker": {},
      "cordova-plugin-certificates": {},
      "cordova-plugin-http": {},
      "cordova-plugin-file": {},
      "cordova-pdf-generator": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic": {
        "APP_ID": "e363211c",
        "CHANNEL_NAME": "Production",
        "UPDATE_METHOD": "background",
        "UPDATE_API": "https://api.ionicjs.com",
        "MAX_STORE": "2"
      },
      "ionic-plugin-keyboard": {},
      "cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION": "24.1.1+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-printer": {},
      "phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION": "27.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-datepicker": {}
    },
    "platforms": [
      "ios",
      "android",
      "browser"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: This could be caulsed of only one thing, that the data that is being stored in an array and viewed and not saved into storage or any place, so when app is killed by restart or force clear app from opened app list, the array is closed, thus its including the old data that are already pushed into array on every time app launch.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Mostafa can you please tell me the process how I am fix it.

Comment: You could either install NativeStorage or Storage to start saving data, and on each time you enter new data , you push the item into storage or native storage, you can search it and get answers, but if you didn't find example, tell me an i could put an answer of the way and installations here.

Comment: There is no storage problem here. My app go to the previous version when I kill the app from background.

Comment: It reflect old vserion UI screens. that is not related to the Storage and Array

Comment: If you console log the data of the storage, will it load all the data or just keep on old ones?

Comment: yes it load new data accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

In your **config.xml** and **package.json** try to change `"UPDATE_METHOD": "background"` to `"UPDATE_METHOD": "none"`

Answer (score 0):

After RND I found that its the problem of ionic dashboard.
Ionic dashboard has channels.We add our git commit on channel to update ionic app.

Here is the details.

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic" spec="^2.0.4">
        <variable name="APP_ID" value="e363211c" />
        <variable name="CHANNEL_NAME" value="Production" />
        <variable name="UPDATE_METHOD" value="background" />
        <variable name="UPDATE_API" value="https://api.ionicjs.com" />
        <variable name="MAX_STORE" value="2" />
    </plugin>
```

In my ionic dashboard 'Production' channel had a old version commit thats why when app is update from ionic dashboard in background it took old version old.

for fixing this issue I add new commit with production channel and app works fine.